# Why are requests being made to /eyeblaster on my website?

Tags: apache, adsense, ads

My Adsense-supported website's error.log file has lots entries like this which I'm fairly sure are advert related:

> [Fri Apr 12 07:19:57 2013] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /var/www/[mywebsite]/htdocs/eyeblaster, referer: http://apac-bidder.mathtag.com/notify/iframe? [snip lots of junk]

What is it and is it harmful?
Should I create an empty eyeblaster.html file to shut it up?

I also have another two that are like it - are they related?:

> [Fri Apr 12 07:08:52 2013] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /var/www/[mywebsite]/htdocs/7196176924447058959
>
> [Fri Apr 12 07:13:58 2013] [error] [client IP] File does not exist: /var/www/[mywebsite]/htdocs/_sans

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462795/determine-which-advertisement-made-a-request-to-eyeblaster-addineyev2-html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at StackOverflow question above - [Determine which advertisement made a request to /eyeblaster/addineyev2.html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462795/determine-which-advertisement-made-a-request-to-eyeblaster-addineyev2-html). I think all will be revealed :).

Comment: I notice that it is asking for /eyeblaster not /eyeblaster/addineyev2.html - any ideas why that might be?

Answer (score 1):

Eyeblaster is an online advertising company now called [Sizmek](http://www.sizmek.com/) (formerly Mediamind).

As John mentioned, this file is used as an iframe buster, just like DoubleClick's iframe buster, which should be placed by a publisher on [www.example.com]/doubleclick/DARTIframe.html

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to disallow eyeblaster.
Just add these to your `robots.txt`:

```
Disallow: /eyeblaster
Disallow: /addineyeV2.html
```

---

Or I prefer to redirect eyeblaster to index.html inside `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (eyeblaster|addineyeV2) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score -4):

eyeblaster is just another piece of malware which most machines end up getting on at one point from what I can tell it hasn't caused any series issues but it is best to remove it from your machine whenever your anti-malware software pics it up

Comment: any links, references, etc would be helpful

Comment: Just completely wrong! - Google documents eyeblaster as an iframe buster https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/1085693?hl=en